# Zend Framework site with Drupal (or any other CMS) in subfolder)

Tags: php, zend-framework, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building web site/application based on Zend Framework. For large number of pages I want to use Drupal. Drupal is presumably installed in /cms folder.

Zend Framework entry point is

> /public/index.php

And for Drupal is

> /public/cms/index.php

How can it be done with some **.htaccess mod_rewrite** rules to remove "/cms/" part for URL for Drupal, that is, I want link to page to be

> www.example.com/blog/a-blog-post

instead of

> www.example.com/cms/blog/a-blog-post

Also, I want my custom Routes from Zend Framework to work properly.

Subquestion: Who will serve 404 not-found page, Zend Framework app or Drupal ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how Drupal handles it's root hostname, but using the default mod_rewrite rules in Zend Framework, anything in the public path that exists as a folder will override the ZF routes.

So I'm guessing if you install Drupal in `public/blog` you could path out to `www.example.com/blog/a-post-name` and it would hit Drupal. At least that's what I do when using Wordpress in conjunction with ZF.

Error pages would be rendered depending on which application is running when the error is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your drupal urls are all '/blog' a single rewrite rule for that should suffice as long as it is interpreted before zend frameworks rewrite rules.

I'm just pulling this from the top of my head, so I hope it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /cms/index.php [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The important [L] tells apache it's the last rule and shouldn't go further.  This *should* work but it might need some massaging.;)

To answer your subquestion, the 404 will be tossed by both.  Anything not found in /blog will be drupal, anything else not found will be ZF.

Comment: OK, that's nice solution when there is only one path for which Drupal is used. What about if there is several Drupal managed paths/categories like /blog/a-blog-post, /faq/some-faqs, /tutorials/a-tutorial, etc... Number of categories in Drupal should potentially be unlimited, but the number of Zend Framework Routes and Controllers will be limited to only a few.

Comment: If you're giving drupal the power to be unlimited and setting ZF to be finite, you might be better off writing the rewrite rules for ZF first, then letting everything else fall to drupal.  It's just a matter of setting the rewrite rules in order of precedence.